# How to add User model to Profile model in Django right way?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql

I am new to Django and trying to create a Profile(Patient) model. Here are my models.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Patient(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)

class Doctor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  max_slots = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
  available = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)

class Assistant(models.Model):
  name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
  docid = models.OneToOneField('Doctor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)

class Appointment(models.Model):
  confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  patid = models.OneToOneField('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  docid = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  assid = models.ForeignKey('Assistant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.patid)
```

Last migration file

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('doctor', '0014_auto_20200318_0219'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='patient',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
```

and error I am getting when I run migrations

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, doctor, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying doctor.0011_auto_20200318_0211...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\syd's\.virtualenvs\django-hospital-0gp1XnhJ\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "doctor_patient" does not exist
```

I tried dropping all my tables and running migrations again but no use.

P.S. The name of my Django app is "doctor" and I am using PostgreSQL. I have ran an initial migration with "username" as a CharField then decided to use the User model as a OneToOneField.

Comment: this could be a patient thing.  Did you run an initial migrate? and can you please add the imports you used at the top?  thanks.

Comment: also, I'm looking at assistant.....should that not be onetomany?

Comment: Yes, I have ran an initial migration with "username" as a CharField then I decided to use the User model as a OneToOneField.
I also added my imports as suggested